# Uploading Image on jsf

Tags: java, jsf, jakarta-ee, jsf-2, glassfish

I want my application to be able to upload images into a directory. The problem is that it sometimes only works after a few tries, although sometimes it works properly. Here is my code:

This is the `DemoBean.java` file

```
private Part file1;
private String imageName;

private static String getFilename(Part part) {
    for (String cd : part.getHeader("content-disposition").split(";")) {
        if (cd.trim().startsWith("filename")) {
            String filename = cd.substring(cd.indexOf('=') + 1).trim().replace("\"", "");
            return filename.substring(filename.lastIndexOf('/') + 1).substring(filename.lastIndexOf('\\') + 1); // MSIE fix.
        }
    }
    return null;
}

public String getImageName() {
    return imageName;
}

public void setImageName(String imageName) {
    this.imageName = imageName;
}

public Part getFile1() {
    return file1;
}

public void setFile1(Part file1) {
    this.file1 = file1;
}

public String upload() throws IOException {

    file1.write("" + getFilename(file1));
    imageName = getFilename(file1);
    String fileName = "";

    try {
        Part filePart = file1;
        fileName = getFilename(filePart);

        InputStream inputStream = null;
        OutputStream outputStream = null;
        try {
            File outputFilePath = new File("c:\\project-images\\" + fileName);
            inputStream = filePart.getInputStream();
            outputStream = new FileOutputStream(outputFilePath);
            int read = 0;
            final byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];
            while ((read = inputStream.read(bytes)) != -1) {
                outputStream.write(bytes, 0, read);
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("shit happened" + e.getCause());

        } finally {
            if (outputStream != null) {
                outputStream.close();
            }
            if (inputStream != null) {
                inputStream.close();
            }
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();

    }
    //reload();
    return "";
}

public void reload() throws IOException {
    ExternalContext ec = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext();
    ec.redirect(((HttpServletRequest) ec.getRequest()).getRequestURI());
}
}
```

And this is the `xhtml` file that uses the bean

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
          xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
          xmlns:ui="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/facelets" xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"
          xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core">
    <ui:composition template="/templates/page-template.xhtml">
        <ui:param name="pageTitle" value="Books"/>
        <ui:define name="panel-main">


            <section>
                <h:form enctype="multipart/form-data">
                    <h2>Add a new Book</h2>
                    <h:panelGrid columns="2" styleClass="form-grid" columnClasses="form-column-label,form-column-input">

                        <h:inputFile value="#{demoBean.file1}">
                            <f:ajax event="change" listener="#{demoBean.upload()}" execute="@form" render="@form"/>


                        </h:inputFile>


                        <c:set value="#{demoBean.imageName}" target="#{newBooks.book}" property="image"/>


                        <h:outputLabel for="Price">Price:</h:outputLabel>
                        <h:inputText id="Price" value="#{newBooks.book.price}" size="20"/>


                        <h:outputText value=""/>
                        <h:commandButton value="Submit" action="#{newBooks.submit}">

                        </h:commandButton>
                    </h:panelGrid>
                </h:form>
            </section>


        </ui:define>
    </ui:composition>
    </html>
```

Comment: `System.out.println("shit happened" + e.getCause());` print the whole statcktrace and tell us what is happening

Comment: if it works sometime and other time it does not the it should be issue with scope of your bean. Try changing the scope.